# Cannot cast android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat to android.widget.ShareActionProvider

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am currently learning android using an online tutorial which can be found at http://www.raywenderlich.com/78576/android-tutorial-for-beginners-part-2

It has been going well so far but I am now having some problems as, even though my code matches that of the tutorial, I get the error message above (the title of this thread).

My imports are as follows...

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import  android.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;
```

I am having problems below, within the if statement...

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu.
    // Adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    // Access the Share Item defined in menu XML
    MenuItem shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);

    // Access the object responsible for
    // putting together the sharing submenu
    if (shareItem != null) {
        mShareActionProvider =  (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(shareItem);
    }

    // Create an Intent to share your content
    setShareIntent();

    return true;
}

private void setShareIntent() {

    if (mShareActionProvider != null) {

        // create an Intent with the contents of the TextView
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Android Development");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mainTextView.getText());

        // Make sure the provider knows
        // it should work with that Intent
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
    }
}
```

I thought it might be due to recent updates causing some code to become outdated but I don't really have much of an idea as I am not that experienced with android.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import the  ShareActionProvider from the support library, like this:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;
```

Since you are supporting older Android versions and using the support library implementation of MenuItemCompat you also need to use the support version of other classes that interact with it, if they are available. You need to watch out when using auto imports, and select the support version if given the choice.

Comment: Thank you, this sorted it out. Good advice. I will watch out for auto imports in the future!